# Best way to compare the values of given column 2-by-2

Tags: python, pandas

I'm triyng to compare the values of given column of my dataframe two-by-two (previous VS current) in order to create a new column.

My input df is the following:

```
            timestamp  charging
0 2017-10-15 18:36:46         1
1 2017-10-15 18:41:54         1
2 2017-10-15 18:46:54         1
3 2017-10-15 18:50:35         1
4 2017-10-15 18:54:14        -1
5 2017-10-15 18:57:54        -1
6 2017-10-15 19:02:47        -1
7 2017-10-15 19:11:41         1
8 2017-10-15 19:21:25         1
9 2017-10-15 19:31:04        -1
```

I want to create new column with the same values of timestamp only when charging value goes from positive to negative or negative to positive.
Output should be:

```
            timestamp  charging period start/end time
0 2017-10-15 18:36:46         1                   NaT
1 2017-10-15 18:41:54         1                   NaT
2 2017-10-15 18:46:54         1                   NaT
3 2017-10-15 18:50:35         1   2017-10-15 18:50:35
4 2017-10-15 18:54:14        -1   2017-10-15 18:54:14
5 2017-10-15 18:57:54        -1                   NaT
6 2017-10-15 19:02:47        -1   2017-10-15 19:02:47
7 2017-10-15 19:11:41         1   2017-10-15 19:11:41
8 2017-10-15 19:21:25         1   2017-10-15 19:21:25
9 2017-10-15 19:31:04        -1   2017-10-15 19:31:04
```

I did this in a bad way (but works) with the following code:

```
df['period start/end time'] = pd.NaT

for ind in df.index:
    if ind > 0:
       if df.at[ind, 'charging'] > 0 and df.at[ind-1, 'charging'] < 0:
          df.at[ind-1, 'period start/end time'] = df.at[ind-1, 'timestamp']
          df.at[ind, 'period start/end time'] = df.at[ind, 'timestamp']

       if df.at[ind, 'charging'] < 0 and df.at[ind-1, 'charging'] > 0:
          df.at[ind-1, 'period start/end time'] = df.at[ind-1, 'timestamp']
          df.at[ind, 'period start/end time'] = df.at[ind, 'timestamp']
```

This takes so much time!, is there anyway to do this faster and better?

Comment: Shouldn't row 8 also have a timestamp?

Comment: yes, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC,

```
mask = (df.charging != df.charging.shift().bfill())
df.loc[mask | mask.shift(-1).fillna(False), 'new']  = df.timestamp

    timestamp             charging  new
0   2017-10-15 18:36:46   1         NaT
1   2017-10-15 18:41:54   1         NaT
2   2017-10-15 18:46:54   1         NaT
3   2017-10-15 18:50:35   1         2017-10-15 18:50:35
4   2017-10-15 18:54:14  -1         2017-10-15 18:54:14
5   2017-10-15 18:57:54  -1         NaT
6   2017-10-15 19:02:47  -1         2017-10-15 19:02:47
7   2017-10-15 19:11:41   1         2017-10-15 19:11:41
8   2017-10-15 19:21:25   1         2017-10-15 19:21:25
9   2017-10-15 19:31:04  -1         2017-10-15 19:31:04
```

Comment: took me a while to figure the logic, but it's quite clever!, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a mask:

```
condition = df.charging.diff().bfill().ne(0) | df.charging.diff().shift(-1).ne(0)
```

Using **`np.where`**

```
df['new'] = np.where(condition, df.timestamp, pd.NaT)   

            timestamp  charging                 new
0  2017-10-1518:36:46         1                 NaT
1  2017-10-1518:41:54         1                 NaT
2  2017-10-1518:46:54         1                 NaT
3  2017-10-1518:50:35         1  2017-10-1518:50:35
4  2017-10-1518:54:14        -1  2017-10-1518:54:14
5  2017-10-1518:57:54        -1                 NaT
6  2017-10-1519:02:47        -1  2017-10-1519:02:47
7  2017-10-1519:11:41         1  2017-10-1519:11:41
8  2017-10-1519:21:25         1  2017-10-1519:21:25
9  2017-10-1519:31:04        -1  2017-10-1519:31:04
```